# Mongoose Error when using findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, findoneandupdate

I have received an error at my server console during updating my Note collection, the update is successful but I receive this error in my server console, felt something wrong. Thanks in advance

```
app.put("/todos/:id", async(req,res) => {
    try {
        // console.log(req.body);
        const { id } = req.params;
        const { title, content } = req.body.edit;
        const edit = await Note.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id}, {
                title: title,
                content: content
            },
            function (err, docs) {
            if(!err){
                console.log("Successfully edit item:" + docs);
                const response = res.json(docs);
            }else{
                console.error(err);
            }
        })
        // Example: Update name to Gourav
        // User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, {
        //         name: 'Gourav'
        //     },
        //     function (err, docs) {
        //         if (err) {
        //             console.log(err)
        //         } else {
        //             console.log("Updated User : ", docs);
        //         }
        //     });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Error msg:

> MongooseError: Query was already executed: Note.findOneAndUpdate({
> _id: new ObjectId("61580e469338c1fc3...
> at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (C:\Users\xx\Desktop\MernToDoV3\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:21:19)
> at C:\Users\xx\Desktop\MernToDoV3\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {   originalStack: 'Error\n' +
> '    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (C:\Users\xx\Desktop\MernToDoV3\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:25:28)\n'
> +
> '    at C:\Users\xx\Desktop\MernToDoV3\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33\n'
> +
> '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue with this query `query.limit(resPerPage).skip(skip)`.

I chained `clone()` and it worked

```
query.limit(resPerPage).skip(skip).clone()
```

Comment: Indeed it helps! Could you enlighten me how it resolve the error?
Previously keep emits error despite all data is successfully edited.
Is it because when I accidentally run the queries for multiple times causing previous errors?

Comment: I think it was becuase mongoose is not allowed to make same queries twice. so somehow mongoose is making 2 queries in a row. with clone it is creating a different copy each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. You don't need to use the callbacks instead use async/await or then/catch.

When you apply try/catch to the async code, it doesn't go well. They are typically used to catch the errors when the code is synchronous by using different means. Promises provided a way to catch the error using catch operator.

```
app.post("/todos", async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        // const small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
        // small.save(function (err) {
        // if (err) return handleError(err);
        // // saved!
        // });

        console.log(req.body); //should use console to see

        const { title, content}  = req.body.newNote,
              noteInput = new Note({title, content });
     
        const result = await noteInput.save();
        
        if (result) {
         // check if the result exist else do something 
         // if you don't find anything
        }

    }catch(err){
        // any errors in the save will be catch here automatically
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```

Note: When you make a function async, you need to use the await keyword to wait for the results for the async portion in the function.

Comment: Sorry, i found that i had attached wrong code snip due to yesterday stackoverflow server issue, never notice until i come back from work, thanks for your reply anyway

Comment: So, Does it work?

Comment: No it does not.